# Insert Data Validation in ever changing sheets using CountA and Offset in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I receive data that is similar in content, yet varies in the number and order of columns. I installed a drop down permanently in A6, copying it to each column in row 6,of the other columns, then select the appropriate header from the list. How can I amend my macro so it would either copy the DV from A6 or create identical headers where required? (determined by countA in Row 5)

[image: See the different sheets here]

This VBA solution places text where I want the dropdowns. Please tell me what I should use to replace the text "same dropdown as A6" so that it will automatically insert a dropdown with the header choices.

```
Private Sub CmdSubmit_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
   For i = 1 To 50
   
   
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Range("A5").Select
    
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value >= "1" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Else
        Selection.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "same drop down as A6"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "same drop down as A6"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "same drop down as A6"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Same drop down as A6"
   Next i
    
End Sub
```

---

This works, but it is not dynamic: Can we make it dynamic?

```
Sub Thiscopypaste()
    Dim rngcopy As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set rngcopy = ActiveSheet.Range("A6")

        rngcopy.Copy

    
    Range("B5").Select
    If ActiveCell.Value >= "1" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    
    Range("C5").Select
    If ActiveCell.Value >= "1" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
     Range("D5").Select
    If ActiveCell.Value >= "1" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    Range("E5").Select
    If ActiveCell.Value >= "1" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    Range("F5").Select
    If ActiveCell.Value >= "1" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hello elaine. It is hard to know exactly what you are asking. Could you please give more information with examples and perhaps a screenshot of what you want. Thx.

Comment: Thank Nerd2000, I have attached the screenshot as a link at the very beginning of my question. I want to be able to insert dropdowns in the cells outlined in red.

Comment: Thank you, Nerd2000. We’re almost there. A copy of the A6 dropdown is only required if cell B5, B6, etc., have values >=1.  (I am sorry I caused the confusion with the example I provided showing four offsets.) I need the insertion of additional dropdowns be dynamic based on whether the counta in row 5 indicates the need for the dropdown. How can this be accomplished?  Thanks! Your kind efforts are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is not cells on the 5th row that need to have values >= 1 (ex. b5, c5, d5, etc...)?

Comment: I updated the answer. that may be what you are looking for. Remember to upvote and accept as your answer if it is what you require. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dropdown you speak of is a data validation list then you need to perform the following:

```
    Private Sub CmdSubmit_Click()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim rngCopy As Range

       For i = 1 To 50

        'ActiveSheet.Select
        Set rngCopy = ActiveSheet.Range("A6")

        rngCopy.Copy

        If rngCopy.Offset(-1, i).Value >= 1 Then
            'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            rngCopy.Offset(0, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Else
            Set rngCopy = rngCopy.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, i)
        End If
        'rngCopy.Offset(0, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        'rngCopy.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        'rngCopy.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        'rngCopy.Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
       Next i

       Set rngCopy = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nerd2000. I do appreciate your assistance. I do not want to copy cell A5, I do need to copy A6 and paste in subsequent row 6 cells "IF" the cell in row 5 above it is >=1.  I used counta in Cell A5, etc so that the dropdowns in row 6 would not be created if there was nothing in the column below row 6. How can I make your formula include the consideration of the values in row 5? Am I looking for how to offset an If statement that includes an offset?

Comment: Hey elaine. It should work for you now. I hope that satisfies what you need.

Comment: Hey Nerd2000! This runs perfectly. I appreciate your brilliant assistance. Thanks for your patience, as well. I upvoted you, as well - and received the message that it won't show, since I'm new.